# How to check whether a value exists in a Ruby structure?

Tags: ruby, arrays, json

I used to have a series of independent arrays (e.g. `name()`, `id()`, `description()` ). I used to be able to check whether a value existed in a specific array by doing `name.include?("Mark")`

Now that I moved to a MUCH MORE elegant way to manage different these independent arrays (here for background: [How do I convert an Array with a JSON string into a JSON object (ruby)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27988514/how-do-i-convert-an-array-with-a-json-string-into-a-json-object-ruby)) I am trying to figure out how I do the same.

In short I put all the independent arrays in a single structure so that I can reference the content as `object().name`, `object().id`, `object().description`.

However I am missing now how I can check whether the `object` array has a value "Mark" in its `name` structure.

I have tried `object.name.include?("Mark")` but it doesn't quite like it.

I have also tried to use `has_value?`but that doesn't seem to be working either (likely because it used to be an hash before I imported it into the structure but right now is no longer a hash - see here: [How do I convert an Array with a JSON string into a JSON object (ruby)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27988514/how-do-i-convert-an-array-with-a-json-string-into-a-json-object-ruby))

Thoughts? How can I check whether object.name contains a certain string?

Thanks.

Comment: `array_of_customers[1][:name].include? 'John'
 #=> true`

Comment: Your question is incomprehensible. How can `name()` (with parenthesis) be an array instead of a method? I can't parse your sentence "... manage different these independent arrays" It is not clear what `object().name`, etc. are doing.  I thought you claimed `name()` to be an array, but now you refer it as "`name` structure". What is that?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion @sawa. I am pretty new to programming so I am trying to use terminology at my best. I can't quite use a proper terminology for what's been suggested in the post I referenced (that works well for what I needed). `object` (per my question above) is essentially an array and the items are a "structure" that has been generated off a hash. In the original hash `name` was a string whose role was the key in the hash key/value pair. Please see the other question linked as there is an output of the array of hash. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find all customers called `Mark` you can write the following:

```
customers_named_mark = array_of_customers.select{|c| c.name == 'Mark' }
```

This will return a potentially empty array.
If you want to find the first customer named `Mark`, write

```
customer_named_mark = array_of_customers.detect{|c| c.name == 'Mark' }
```

This will return the first matching item or nil.

Comment: Thanks @nathanvda. I thought there was some sort of shortcut (e.g. include? or has_value?) Vs having to traverse the entire array but this will do! Thanks!

Comment: @mreferre I'm pretty sure both `Array#include?` and `Hash#has_value?` also transverse the entire array/hash.

Comment: @ajedi check the documentation for [Array#include?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-include-3F) : you have to give it an identical value, it uses the equality operator. In this case you want to find all customers inside an array of customers with a given name. Unless you use a custom class, and define an equality operator that will make sure the `Customer.new(name: 'Freddy') == 'Freddy'` (which I would avoid) you will have to use  the given solution.

Comment: @nathanvda Please read the comment I was replying to. I was _not_ saying that the use of `Array#include?` or `Hash#has_value?` would be an appropriate solution to this problem. I was simply correcting a misunderstanding the OP seemed to be having about the implementation of those methods.