# Passing arrays of hash from Sinatra to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby, arrays, json

I have two different array formats I need to pass to JavaScript for some form of rendering. I don't have to use both formats, I will pick one based on what's easiest to pass to JS.

1) The first format is the one described in this other question: [How do I convert an Array with a JSON string into a JSON object (ruby)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27988514/how-do-i-convert-an-array-with-a-json-string-into-a-json-object-ruby)
It's essentially an array of items that represent a custom structure that has been created off an original hash.
In my ruby program I can refer to a value as `customer[3].name`

2) the second format is an array of items that are more like a native hash. So in my ruby program I can refer to them as `customer[3]["name"]`. It is important to note that in this format "name" isn't a symbol but rather a string (that is what I get as input).

For my preliminary tests I have used gon-sinatra (https://github.com/gazay/gon-sinatra) to pass variables from Sinatra to JS. It works fine as I have access to my gon.customers array in JS but I can't find a way/syntax to extract (in JS) all customers' names (for example) or all customers' id's or all customers' descriptions and manipulate them in my JS code.

At this point I am not sure if my problem is the hand-off from Sinatra to JavaScript, or if the hands-off is ok and I am just having a hard time with the basic JS syntax.

I am not bound to use either array formats (I am flexible) nor I am bound to use gon-sinatra (albeit it appears that it makes the hand-off totally transparent).

Suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: `console.log(gon.customers)` in dev console and examine your array’s values?

Comment: Ok. That sounds like a good idea. Silly me. Let's focus on the one that has "native" hash in it (the other seems to be more cumbersome to manage at first look in console). I have 4 objects in my array. The first line says `[Object][Object][Object][Object]`. If you expand it you see `0: Object`, `1: Object`, `2: Object`, `3: Object` and each of them have the proper `id`, `name` and `description` keys with the values I expect. It appears to boil down to how I access these values in the code. Any hints on the syntax I should use? Thanks @mudasobwa !

Comment: BTW, both `gon.customer[0]['name']` and `gon.customer[0].name` should work. You are welcome.

Comment: @mudasobwa `gon.customer[0]["name"]` (with the hash as an item in the array) works fine. For some reasons `gon.customer[0].name` doesn't (with the ruby structure as an item in the array). I am more than ok to use the former, however what I need is to pass to a JS function an array of values as input. So I would need to reference ALL the customers' names. Something like `gon.customer[]["name"]` or `gon.customer["name"]` or... THANKS!

Comment: [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) would do the trick: `gon.customer.map(function(el) { return el['name']; });`.

Comment: That seems to make trick. If I `console.log(gon.customer.map(function(el) { return el['name']; })` I get `["Mark", "Joe", "Anna", "George"]` which is what I wanted. Now the JS function doesn't do what I was expecting but that may be another problem. I need to double check with someone on this. Thanks so far! @mudasobwa